# First and Second Call in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to generate a random number between 1 and 6, on every second call a random number between one and six is suppose to be generated and on every other call 6 is suppose to be exported to both pointers, I keep getting the output in the opposite behaviour could someone suggest how to rectify this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void loadedDice(int*, int*);

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    loadedDice(&a, &b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    loadedDice(&a, &b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    loadedDice(&a, &b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);

    return 0;

}


void loadedDice(int* export1, int* export2)
{
    if(*export1 == 6 && *export2 == 6)
    {
    *export1 = 1 + (rand()%6);
    *export2 = 1 + (rand()%6);

    } else {
    *export1 = 6;
    *export2 = 6;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are getting and what to you want to get? Be laconic.

Comment: At the moment output is: 6 6 -> 2 3 -> 6 6, I want it to be like 2 3 -> 6 6 -> 1 5

Comment: The first printf will you give every time 6 and 6 since both are 0 and your checking if the are 6 in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
void loadedDice(int* export1, int* export2) {
  if (*export1 == 0 && *export2 == 0) {
    *export1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    *export2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
  } else if (*export1 == 6 && *export2 == 6) {
    *export1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    *export2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);

  } else {
    *export1 = 6;
    *export2 = 6;
  }
}
```

Now, since the initial values are 0, you will produce the random numbers at first call.

---

Or you could simply initialize your variables to 6, which will not require you to change your function and it is recommended, for readability and maintenance (keeping functions as small as possible).

This method requires minor changes to your code, specifically you should change the initialization in `main()` to this:

```
int a = 6, b = 6;
```

---

If you don't want to get your variables initialized, then you could use an initializing function, which should assign random values to the variables, without performing any check first (because the values are uninitialized).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void loadedDice(int*, int*);
void init_loadedDice(int*, int*);

int main(void) {
  int a, b;

  srand(time(NULL));
  init_loadedDice(&a, &b);
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
  loadedDice(&a, &b);
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
  loadedDice(&a, &b);
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);

  return 0;

}

void init_loadedDice(int* export1, int* export2) {
  *export1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
  *export2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
}

void loadedDice(int* export1, int* export2) {
  if (*export1 == 6 && *export2 == 6) {
    *export1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    *export2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);

  } else {
    *export1 = 6;
    *export2 = 6;
  }
}
```

---

If you really don't want to use a second function (which is recommended) and don't want to initialize your variables in main, you could use a flag for the function (but I don't see why doing it this way):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void loadedDice(int*, int*, int*);

int main(void) {
  // flag, named 'uninit' will be one
  // as long as 'a' and 'b' are uninitialized
  int a, b, uninit = 1;

  srand(time(NULL));
  loadedDice(&a, &b, &uninit);
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
  loadedDice(&a, &b, &uninit);
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
  loadedDice(&a, &b, &uninit);
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);

  return 0;

}

void loadedDice(int* export1, int* export2, int* uninit) {
  if(*uninit) {
    *export1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    *export2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    *uninit = 0; // change the value of the flag
  } else if (*export1 == 6 && *export2 == 6) {
    *export1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    *export2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);

  } else {
    *export1 = 6;
    *export2 = 6;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome @IamTrent, however I saw that there is an easier way, check my edit!

Comment: What if the first variables weren't initialised, what would be another possible method?

Comment: Then you would need a function that would assign values to the variables without checking anything. Do you want an example of this? @IamTrent

Comment: Yes thanks, would it be possible to achieve this within the same function?

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize `a` and `b` to 6 instead of 0

```
    int a = 6, b = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method based on G. Samaras answer:

```
void loadedDice(int* export1, int* export2) {
    static int check = 1;
  if (check == 1) {
    *export1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    *export2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    check = 0;
  } else if (*export1 == 6 && *export2 == 6) {
    *export1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    *export2 = 1 + (rand() % 6);   
  } else {
    *export1 = 6;
    *export2 = 6;
  }
```